# Using semaphore , Sync two threads Patient and Assistant

Tags: multithreading, mutex, synchronization, semaphore

I was asked this question in an interview for a very prestigious group in a company(I cannot tell the name)
I was stack with this question for a while, I generated possible solutions to them but I want to make sure my solution was correct, Please comment or fix my solution or guide me to a solution or show if my solution has Deadlock, starvation etc...,

this is the problem:

Patients go to the Bio Lab to work. The Lab contains numMachines.  In the Lab there is an supervisor that will assign one machine to each patient if there are available machines.   After a patient finishes her work, she releases the machine and waits until another two patients are done.   When the group has 3 patients formed they leave.

Use semaphores and operations on semaphores, synchronize the two types of threads: Patient and Supervisor

```
binary semaphore mutex=1

counting semaphore machine =5 , done =0

Patient:

P(machine); 
V(done);
P(mutex);

waitingPatient++;

if(waitingPatient==groupSize){
    for(int i=0’i<groupSize;i++){
        V(waiting);
}

waitingPatient=0;
P(waiting);
V(mutex);
}

else{
    P(waiting);
    V(mutex);
}

Assistant:

while(true){
    P(done);
    V(machine);
}
```